# appendChild or append or insert - nothing is working. TD is inserting wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am having a devil of a time here. This seems sooo easy, YET I can't get it to work.
My goal is to just insert/append/appendChild a TD after another TD... so you'd have..

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="eve"></td>
<td class="mo"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

simple right? naw.

Here is my code.

```
  var r = new Element('tr',{'class':'trclass'});
  var td2 = new Element('td',{'class':'mo'});
  var artDiv = new Element('div',{'class':'summary'});
  var td = new Element('td',{'class':'eve'});
  var div = new Element('div',{'class':'pad1','style':'overflow=hidden'});
```

I set up some elements.

```
   div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + disp.link + '" class="Link">somelink</a>';
artDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="'+ disp.link +'" class="url">' + disp.name  +'</a>';
td2.innerHTML = '<div class="pad1"><a href="' + disp.link + '" class="mo">' + disp.linkName  +'</a></div>';

  div.appendChild(artDiv);
   td.appendChild( div );
    r.appendChild(td);
    r.appendChild(td2)
```

I have tried using prototype only, jquery only etc.. and when I try to do this in console, I can get it to work. BUT when it is sitting in a page, no matter what I do...

I get this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="mo"></td> <-- THIS should be last TD, but no matter what, always goes first.
<td class="eve"></td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the solution in jQuery or prototype?

using jQuery, an easy solution would be to first add a id/class to your table. after that, it is pretty straight foward:

```
$(function() {
  var tdElement = "<td class='eve'></td>"; //the element you are inserting

  //lets say your table class is 'foo'
  $('.foo > tr').append(tdElement);
});
```

now this is assuming you only have one row. But this will append tdElement to the tr element.

Comment: I have multiple TR's but they happen synchronously... each "grouping of data" is passed in to the function. Function creates the TR and needed TD's... as explained in OP.

Comment: in that case, since you have a class on each tr, as long as each tr has a unique class, you can replace '.foo > tr' with '.trClassName' and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assign an ID to the TRs as they're created you should be able to append to them with jQuery in a pretty straightforward manner. Here's a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6agVs/) of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var td1 = "<td class='mo'>Cell Mo</td>"
    var td2 = "<td class='eve'>Cell Eve</td>"
    $("#targetRow").append(td1);
    $("#targetRow").append(td2);
});​
```

If you can't assign the TRs ID values but know what order they're in within the table you could always select on just the table's TRs and use eq() to address them as another option.

Comment: Why does there seem to be an issue with using "new Element" with you implementation? Is their interpolation issues, you think? I was just trying to modify your code a little and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @jamesemanon - Not sure, James. I would have expected that modification to work.